# How to delete columns from Excel

Tags: excel

```
Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 Value 4 Value 5 Value 6
123     3       43      567     53      3
111     123     2       3       9       0
8       8       3       2       3       98
```

So I have 5 columns where user can write values. All the rest of columns have to be invisible, or deleted. I don't want to blank, hide or block them, or remove values from them. I want them to not exist.

Comment: Just select the columns and delete them?

Comment: If this is a programming related question, make clear what programming language, and even more, what you have tried already. If not programming related, try [su].

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you mean. Try using the [PageBreak view](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n71ZZ.png)

Comment: PageBreak looks good, but the user can still write in the rest of columns. It's not a solution.

Comment: @Jerry That not what he wants. How many of them can be deleted? Thats' not a good one..

Comment: *Deleting* doesn't work, because when you delete one column, new empty column adds in in the end of the sheet. Only hidding works

Comment: @simoco i was going to say the same, and the non relevant answer is voted up. How to hide all of them?? That is the question

Comment: as OP said `only the first 5 columns must remain.` - i.e. `A:E`. In that case you could select *entire* column `F` and then press `CTRL`+`RIGHT ARROW` to select *all* columns to right from column `E` and then hide them.

Comment: Nabin I asked because it wasn't entirely clear to me. If you understand, that's good. @user2786496 What about protecting the columns? And why do you mentioned not block them?

Comment: @simoco the user can chage it back again. I don't want him to have that possibility.

Comment: @user2786496, `I want them to not exist` - actually you can't do this. One way is to hide them and then *protect* sheet (maybe with password)

Comment: I think you need a separate software. :-)

Comment: @Jerry because the user can't see the other collums, hiding does not work either, because he can change it back again. i want only the first 5 collumns to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First unlock the first 5 columns:

[image]

Then, hide the other columns:

[image]

Then go to Review > Protect Sheet, then uncheck Select Locked Cells (columns cannot be unhidden if they cannot be selected in the first place):

[image]

Use some password and save. Only users with the password will be able to unhide the columns.

Answer (score 1):

only for the first 5 columns to remain A:E. In that case you could select entire column F and then press

```
CTRL+RIGHT ARROW
```

to select all columns to right from column E and then

```
hide them
```

This is what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can  right cick the columns in the top. Lets say "a" right click and then *Hide. i hope this helps ;)!

Comment: As I wrote, i don't want to blank cloumns.

Comment: I want to delete almost all of them. only the first 5 columns must remain. problem is, that users write where they not supposed to.

Comment: It was correct, but not were what you're looking for.

Comment: but you should give relevant answer, not just the correct one